# Can't find corresponding options in right-click menu and File Properties dialog box in Visual studio 2019 after install AntlrVSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio, antlr, antlr4, antlr4cs

I install AntlrVSIX by nuget. I can find AntlrVSIX in “Extensions” menu. Highlight is also working properly in .g and.g4 file.

But I can't find “AntlrVSIX” in right-click menu and can't set the Build Action under the File Properties dialog box to "ANTLR 4 grammar"

Comment: Go to Menu => Help => About Microsoft Visual Studio, and check what version of Visual Studio 2019 are you using. It should be for 16.8.x. Anything less, and the extension may not work. Microsoft's LSP Client code has a separate assembly for each version, but 8.3 of the extension is for 16.8 only. Otherwise, use VSCode, or raw text in VS2019 to edit. Semantic highlighting (colorization) should be disabled in v8.3 by default. For further information, please email me directly (see the readme.md file).

Comment: For the build actions, make sure to add references to Antlr4BuildTasks and Antlr4.Standard.Runtime to your .csproj file. Building a C# program for Antlr is completely separate from the editing support for an Antlr grammar app. If you need further help, please email me.